# Javascript regex with varying input

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to filter out the following information out of a long piece of text. Which I copy
and paste in a textfield and then want to process into a table as a result. with

- Name
- Address
- Status

Example snippet:(Kind of randomized the names and addresses etc)

```
Thuisprikindeling voor: Vrijdag 15 Mei 2015 DE SMART BON 22 afspraken
Pagina 1/4
Persoonlijke mededeling:
Algemene mededeling:
Prikpostgegevens: REEK-Eeklo extern, (-)
Telefoonnummer Fax Mobiel 0499/9999999 Email dummy.dummy@gmail.com
DUMMY FOO V Stationstreet 2 8000 New York F N - Sober BSN: 1655
THUIS Analyses: Werknr: PIN: 000000002038905
Opdrachtgever: Laboratorium Arts:
Mededeling:  Some comments // VERY DIFFICULT
FO DUMMY FOO V Butterstreet 6 8740 Melbourne F N - Sober BSN: 15898
THUIS Analyses: Werknr: AFD 3 PIN: 000000002035900
Opdrachtgever: Laboratorium Arts:
Mededeling: ZH BLA / BLA BLA - AFD 3 - SOCIAL BEER
JOHN FOOO V Waterstreet 1 9990 Rome F N - Sober BSN: 17878
THUIS / Analyses: Werknr: K111 PIN: 000000002037888
Opdrachtgever: Laboratorium Arts:
Mededeling: TRYOUT/FOO
FO SMOOTH M.FOO M Queen Elisabethstreet 19 9990 Paris F NN - Not Sober BSN: 14877
```

What I want to get out of it is this:

```
DUMMY FOO Stationstreet 2 8000 New York Sober
FO DUMMY FOO Butterstreet 6 8740 Melbourne Sober
JOHN FOOO Waterstreet 1 9990 Rome Sober
FO SMOOTH M.FOO Queen Elisabethstreet 19 9990 Paris Not sober
```

My strategy for the moment is using the following:

- Filter all the lines with at least two words in capitals at the beginning of the line. AND a 4 digit postal code.
- Then discard all the other lines as I only need the lines with the names and adresses
- Then I strip out all the information needed for that line
- Strip the name / address / status

I use the following code:

```
  //Regular expressions

    //Filter all lines which start with at least two UPPERCASE words following a space
    pattern = /^(([A-Z'.* ]{2,} ){2,}[A-Z]{1,})(?=.*BSN)/;
    postcode = /\d{4}/;
    searchSober= /(N - Sober)+/;
    searchNotSober= /(NN - Not sober)+/;

    adres = inputText.split('\n');


    for (var i = 0; i < adres.length; i++) {

        // If in one line And a postcode and which starts with at least
        // two UPPERCASE words following a space
        temp = adres[i]

        if (  pattern.test(temp) && postcode.test(temp)) {

            //Remove BSN in order to be able to use digits to sort out the postal code
            temp = temp.replace( /BSN.*/g, "");

            // Example: DUMMY FOO V Stationstreet 2 8000 New York F N - Sober

            //Selection of the name, always take first part of the array
            // DUMMY FOO
            var name = temp.match(/^([-A-Z'*.]{2,} ){1,}[-A-Z.]{2,}/)[0];

            //remove the name from the string
            temp = temp.replace(/^([-A-Z'*.]{2,} ){1,}[-A-Z.]{2,}/, "");
            // V Stationstreet 2 8000 New York F N - Sober

            //filter out gender
            //Using jquery trim for whitespace trimming
            // V
            var gender = $.trim(temp.match(/^( [A-Z'*.]{1} )/)[0]);

            //remove gender
            temp = temp.replace(/^( [A-Z'*.]{1} )/, "");

            // Stationstreet 2 8000 New York F N - Sober
            //looking for status

            var status = "unknown";
            if ( searchNotsober.test(temp) ) {
                status = "Not soberr";
            }
            else if ( searchSober.test(temp) ) {
                status = "Sober";


            }
            else {
                status = "unknown";
            }

            //Selection of the address /^.*[0-9]{4}.[\w-]{2,40}/
            //Stationstreet 2 8000 New York
            var address = $.trim(temp.match(/^.*[0-9]{4}.[\w-]{2,40}/gm));

            //assemble into person object.
            var person={name: name + "", address: address + "", gender: gender +"", status:status + "", location:[] , marker:[]};
            result.push(person);
        }
    }
```

The problem I have now is that:

- Sometimes the names are not written in CAPITALS
- Sometimes the postal code is not added so my code just stops working.
- Sometimes they put a * in front of the name

A broader question is what strategy can you take to tackle these type of messy input problems?
Should I make cases for every mistake I see in these snippets I get? I feel like
I don't really know exactly what I will get out of this piece of code every time I run
it with different input.

Comment: In order to write a program to do something, you need to be able to describe what it should do precisely. If you can't figure out what to do with the non-conforming input, you can't write a program to do it.

Comment: I could add something which checks most common mistakes or so? The thing is, that as a human its obvious to see what the names are etc. Or what is wrong. I wonder how I could make my program more knowledgeable

Comment: This is why most programs don't allow free-form input, they have separate fields for the address, postal code, etc. And they use menus when there's a known list of inputs. If you don't allow flexible input, you don't have to write a complicated parser. Processing natural language is hard.

Comment: I agree but I have no control over that input so I have to try to work around it by using I suppose regexes?

Comment: Regex alone doesn't seem to be enough, you also need a dictionary, but what if someone is called "John Smith Junior" and lives at "High Street" but there is also a "Junior High Street" where a "John Smith" lives... which one is it?

Comment: Although you could write regexes and for the ambiguous lines you ask the user if it is an address and what is what when processing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a general way of handling it:

1. Find all lines that are most likely matches. Match on "Sober" or whatever makes it unlikely to miss a match, even if it gives you false positives.
2. Filter out false positives, this you have to update and tweak as you go. Make sure you only filter out what isn't relevant at all.
3. Strict filtering of input, what doesn't match gets logged/reported for manual handling, what does match now conforms to a known strict pattern
4. Normalize and extract data should now be much easier since you have limited possible input at this stage

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. What I did already is changing my regexes based on the BSN word which is always there. I will have to make a manual step where I flag what is not really sure. Based on @maraca comment